# XSLT 1.0 Adding values together in string

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to add up numbers in a string using XSLT 1.0
I have a string in a variable called cols and an example value of the variable is "10 20 30 20pt"
I am trying to add the numbers in that string (space delimited) into a variable called total_width as 80pt (or 80) and that variable will be used later.
Thanks!

I tried to create recursive function, but it didn't work. I am getting error.
`<xsl:variable name="total_width">
<xsl:call-template name="get_total_width">
<xsl:with-param name="cols" select="concat(@cols, ' ')"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

```
<xsl:template name="get_total_width">  
    <xsl:param name="cols"/>  
    <xsl:choose>  
        <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($cols))">  
            <xsl:variable name="first_col">  
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(substring-before($cols, ' '), 'pt')"/>  
            </xsl:variable>  
            <xsl:variable name="rest_cols">  
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($cols, ' ')"/>  
            </xsl:variable>  

            $first_col +  
            <xsl:call-template name="get_total_width">  
                <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="concat($rest_cols, ' ')"/>  
            </xsl:call-template>  
        </xsl:when>  
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>  
    </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>  `
```

I figured there must be an easier way to do this than what I am trying to do above.
Thanks!

Comment: 1. Is that the **exact** format of the values in the variable? Numbers separated by space, with the last value having the unit appended, with no space? 2. Which XSLT processor are you using? You could possibly use some extension functions here. if your processor supports them.

Comment: 3. You say you use XSLT 1.0 - but the `replace()` function requires at least XSLT 2.0.

Comment: 1. Yes, that was format, but the it can have more or less numbers in the string.
2. BI Publisher - not sure what it supports
3. Yes, replace was a problem. I've changed to use translate.
Thanks!

Comment: You can identify the processor engine and the XSLT version it supports as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153. You can test if it supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function by looking at the result of `<xsl:value-of select="function-available('str:tokenize')" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"/>`.

Comment: Vendor is Oracle Corporation. And the function is returning false.

Comment: I am not familiar with that processor. I presume the supported version is 1.0? If you can find the documentation, you can see if it provides any extension functions of its own that could help you with the tokenizing. Otherwise you will need to use the first option in the provided answer (again, assuming it's XSLT 1.0 only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no really simple way to do this purely in XSLT 1.0. You will need something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="cols">10 20 30 20pt</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="total">
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-tokens">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="translate($cols, 'pt', '')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-tokens">
    <xsl:param name="string"/> 
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:param name="previous-result" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($string, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="$previous-result + $token"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-tokens">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="previous-result" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, if your processor supports the str:tokenize extension function, you could reduce all that to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="cols">10 20 30 20pt</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="total" select="sum(str:tokenize(translate($cols, 'pt', ''), ' '))"/>
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked except I had to change the otherwise to select $previous_result to make it work. Thanks!!

Comment: If you change the `<otherwise>` to output the value of `$previous_result` then the last token will not be added to the total. In the given example, the result will be 60 instead of the expected 80.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. In my original example above, you can see that I was adding space delimiter right in the beginning when calling get_total_width so that's why it wasn't working the way you had it. I've changed it on my side to not add that space and your solution works as is. Thanks again.